# Creating table's and div's in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json

I've got a javascript document where I'm getting a json object and I want to create div's because I can have more than an instance on the json array. I'm creating an article , changing his innerHTML and adding it to the body but it doesn't get added.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'myURL',
    type: "GET",
    data: query,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
      alert(data);
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
      { 
        var _body = document.getElementsByTagName('body') [0];
        alert(_body.innerHTML);
        var article = document.createElement('article');
        article.id = 'invoiceno'+i;
        article.innerHTML = '<div id="client"></div><table class="cabecalho"><tr><th><span>Invoice #</span></th><td id="invoiceno"><span>invoiceno</span></td></tr><tr><th><span>Date</span></th><td id="invoicedate"><span>invoicedate</span></td></tr></table><table class="total"><tr><th><span >Total</span></th><td><span data-prefix>€</span><span id="tots">(TotalAPagar)</span></td></tr></table>';
        alert(article.innerHTML);
        _body.appendChild(article);
        $("#invoiceno"+i).html(data[i].InvoiceNo);
        $("#invoicedate"+i).html(data[i].InvoiceDate);
        $("#client"+i).html(data[i].CompanyName);
        $("#tots"+i).html(data[i].GrossTotal);
      } 
    }
});
```

Comment: Is it specifically only the article element that doesn't get added to the document?

Comment: yes, the article element doesn't get added. the rest is added in the article element, so If it doesn't get added the data won't get added aswell

Comment: It seems to be working fine for me, see this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X6FkB/1/)

Comment: it worked with your code. is it possible that because of me adding the i to the id is making some kind of error? I wanted to add the i to every id on the innerhtml so I can have more articles and reference to them. how can I do that? thanks for your patience and time!

Comment: I strongly doubt it. Try pressing f12 in your browser to open the console and see if it gives you any errors when you refresh the page.

Comment: It added the article to the page, but the data fields are not being add. And is there any way for me to add articles and put the table id = cabecalho+i ?

Comment: I've managed to do it. Thank you so much for you time! Cheers m8